# Running an opencv based python script on a remote server with ssh forwarding from my macbook gives me an error

Tags: python, opencv, ssh, x11-forwarding

I am trying to run a python script on a remote server, which includes displaying images. The image does not get displayed and I get an error `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

I have checked posts where they suggest editing the flags in `sshd_config` and also setting the `DISPLAY` variable manually. But, none of that seems to be working for me.

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
XAuthLocation /usr/X11/bin/xauth
```

Running `xclock` or `xeyes` also gives me errors.

Edit: I used ssh -X and ssh -Y to ssh into the server, neither worked

Comment: Try `ssh -Y` into remote server.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: Restart after installing XQuartz**

After looking through multiple posts and trying to make it work, I realised that after installing XQuartz, the user is required to restart the machine. It allows to set the correct environment variables (like `DISPLAY`). It works for me now after having restarted.

**Alternative**

However, in case you face a similar problem, not stemming due to the restart issue, I found an alternate way as suggested in the following link:

https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=280461906